# Setting field in IronPython resulting in None value

Tags: c#, python, .net, ironpython

I have an issue using IronPython. I created a C# DLL in which I have a class that looks like this :

```
namespace MyNamespace
{

    public static class MyClass
    {

       public struct Parameters
       {
           public String str1;
           public String str2;
           public int anIntValue;
       }

       public static void MyMethod(Parameters param, out Double Result, ref String msg)
       {
           //...Stuff...
       }
```

And the code in IronPython looks like this :

```
import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath("C:\MyPath\MyFile.dll")

from MyFile import MyNamespace

obj = MyClass()
obj.anIntValue = 8
print obj.anIntValue
```

It outputs the value "0" and I get a warning :

```
RuntimeWarning: Setting field anIntValue on value type MyClass may result in updating a copy. 
Use MyClass.anIntValue.SetValue(instance, value)...
```

So I tried the following :

```
MyClass.anIntValue.SetValue(obj.anIntValue,8)
```

And I get the following error :

```
ValueError : Field 'anIntValue' defined on type 'MyNamespace.MyClass' is not
a field on the target object which is of type 'System.Int32'.
```

So basically, the only thing I would like to do, is to create an object from "MyClass" and assign values to its attributes, but when I tried to do it the "standard way", like `anAttribute = aValue`, If I understand this correctly, it only copies the value into a temporary object and not to the object I want to modify.

Am I missing something here ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Not at all familiar with IronPython, but from a C# point of view It looks like your values are all hiding within the struct "Parameters".  So it would make sense that anIntValue is not defined on the MyClass object since it is defined under MyClass.Parameters.anIntValue.  Does it work if you expose anIntValue directly as a member of the class?

Comment: This is actually an error on my part, obj = MyClass.Parameters() is really how I wrote it in IronPython code. (I can't seem to have privileges to edit my own question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it because actually,

the instance I had to call in

```
 MyClass.Parameters.anIntValue.SetValue(instance,value)
```

was not :

```
MyClass.Parameters.anIntValue.SetValue(obj.anIntValue,8)
```

but rather :

```
MyClass.Parameters.anIntValue.SetValue(obj,8)
```